# Amazon MWS SubmitFeed _UPLOAD_VAT_INVOICE_ metadata

Tags: http, metadata, amazon-mws, invoice

I use Amazon MWS SubmitFeed for sending tracking numbers and want to use it now for uploading invoices, pdf. The metadata, metadata:shippingid or metadata:orderid, mus be added, but I have no idea where. To the header?

```
Host: mws.amazonservices.de\r\nx-amazon-user-.... + metadata:shippingid=XXXXX\r\n
```

Or in URI/URL?

```
CString url= L"POST\nmws.amazonservices.de\n/\nAWSAccessKeyId=";
    url += AmazonMWS::GetInstance().GetAccessKey();
    url += L"&Action=SubmitFeed";

    url += L"&ContentMD5Value=";
    url += md5sum;

url += &metadata:shipping=XXXX....
```

I have no idea. Sorry. Does anybody knows where this elements are added to? I use WinHttp.

Answer (score 0):

Formj an example found I got:

URI/URL

```
url += L"&FeedType=_UPLOAD_VAT_INVOICE_";
url += L"&FeedOptions=metadata%3Aorderid%3DXXXXX;.....";
```

Just URL-encoded.